# Html.BeginForm posted Model is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

Hello I have following problem:
I tried to post a Model through a Form to an other controller-action.
But the received Model is only filled with `null` elements.
[image]

**ToolController.cs**

```
public class ToolController : Controller
{    
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Model = new EditToolModel{ /* Some data */ };
        return View(Model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditToolOverview(EditToolModel myModel)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tool", new { show = "overview" });
    }
}
```

**EditToolModel.cs**

```
public class EditToolModel
{
    public Tools tool;
    public IEnumerable<Tools> tools { get; set; }

    public ToolsExtention tool_extention;
    public string latest_version { get; set; }
    public string latest_version_type { get; set; }
    public string latest_devStep { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ToolVersionsView> versions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DevelopmentStep> developmentSteps { get; set; }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model EditToolModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Layout/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Html.Partial("ToolOverview", this.Model)
```

**ToolOverview.cshtml**

```
@model EditToolModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditToolOverview", "Tool", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="contend">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.tool_extention.a)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.tool_extention.b)
        <input type="submit" name="tool_submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Not `@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.tool_extention.a)` but `@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.tool_extention.a)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have a getter/setter on the `tool_extention` property in order for the `DefaultModelBinder` to work

```
public ToolsExtention tool_extention { get; set; }
```

Ditto for the `tool` property (but your only rendering controls for the `tool_extention` property in your view)

Comment: thank you, much appreciate it. It solved my problem.
thought getter and setter at the variables in `tool_extention` are enough.

Comment: I assumed so based on the view, but if your only rendering controls for `ToolsExtention`, why not just make your model `ToolsExtention` (and post it back rather than making the model `EditToolModel`?

Comment: I have more things to render, but I didn't wanted to post my whole code only for the form Problem

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have been searching for couple of hours for this answer: "You need to have a getter/setter on the tool_extention property in order for the DefaultModelBinder to work". I found tons of posts on model values being blank but this is the one that solved my problems. Many many thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Helped me very well

Answer (score -1):

ToolsExtention Try changing the EditToolOverview property from EditToolModel to ToolsExtention in the form post method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditToolOverview(ToolsExtention myModel)
{
    //_devProv.changeToolExtention(myModel);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tool", new { show = "overview" });
}
```